# Is it possible to run a discord music bot on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, discord.py

I've seen several people getting errors when they try to run their discord.py music bot on Heroku using youtube.dl, so is it possible to run them on Heroku? I was wondering if that's code related or gotta go with another VPS? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. To do this you will need to go to this link: [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli)
and then follow the steps there!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).